# Select and where clausule on Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, select, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

Im trying to get three columns of my DB, but I don't get it...

I can use this code. But this way returned all the columns, and only I want three of them.

```
User::where('name', 'LIKE', $term)->get()
```

And I know use this other code: But... in them I cannot use the "where" clausule.

```
User::select(array('id', 'name', 'email'))
```

Anybody know one way to merge the both codes? Perhaps the only way to do that is using Fluent?

Comment: Seems like you should just get all columns and then drop the ones you don't need. Get them all, then filter for what you want.

Comment: @MikeLyons Thanks for your comment: If you are interested, Tim Lewis resolved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So chain them together. Eloquent lets you add any number of statements together until you call one of the closures `get()` or `first()`:

```
$users = User::select(array('id', 'name', 'email'))->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
```

After calling the above, you can call a foreach to show all the results:

```
foreach($users AS $user){
  echo $user->id;
  echo $user->name;
  echo $user->email;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much: you was be very helpful. :) (In five minutes I will choose your answer how the best.)

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote and select my answer so others can use it too. Cheers!